# My Simple Score System Isn't working please help

Tags: unity, c#, game-design

```
using UnityEngine;

/// Handle hitpoints and damages
public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// Total hitpoints
    public int hp = 2;
    /// Score System
    public int score;

    /// Enemy or player?
    public bool isEnemy = true;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    /// Inflicts damage and check if the object should be destroyed
    public void Damage(int damageCount)
    {
        hp -= damageCount;
        SoundEffectsHelper.Instance.MakeplayerHitSound();

        if (hp <= 0)
        {    
            SpecialEffectsHelper.Instance.Explosion(transform.position);
            SoundEffectsHelper.Instance.MakeExplosionSound();
            // Dead!

            if (isEnemy == false)
            {
                Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
            }
            if (isEnemy ==true)
            {
                ///when health reaches 0 object is destroyed and awards the player 100 points.
                Destroy(gameObject);
                score += 100;
            } 
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {

        if (isEnemy == false)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("score:  " + score.ToString());
            GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 350, Screen.height / 2 - 250, 100, 100));
            GUI.color = Color.red;
            GUI.Box(new Rect (10, 40, 80, 30),"Health: " + hp.ToString());
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider)
    {
        // Is this a shot?
        ShotScript shot = otherCollider.gameObject.GetComponent<ShotScript>();
        if (shot != null)
        {
            // Avoid friendly fire
            if (shot.isEnemyShot != isEnemy)
            {
                Damage(shot.damage);

                // Destroy the shot
                Destroy(shot.gameObject); // Remember to always target the game object, otherwise you will just remove the script
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The score displays but doesn't attribute points when the enemy dies what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: This might be a good point to use the debugger and print values to console.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign this script to every enemy and player, then every enemy and player has their own `score`. When an object dies, it adds 100 to *its own* score, not the score of the player which killed it.

Possible options to fix this are:

- change `int score` to `static int score`, which means that the value is shared between all instances of the behavior. This is the most simple solution, but will only work for singleplayer.
- When you want to support multiplayer where each player has an own score, remove the score counting from this class and move it into a different script which only exists once per player. You should add a reference to that script to your `ShotScript` behavior. That way you can keep track of which player fired a shot and use that reference to award the score to the right player.

Answer (score 0):

I got the script working with a little help thanks for all your input. by putting the score in a separate script and defining the player object in this script it works perfectly.

```
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Handle hitpoints and damages
/// </summary>
public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Total hitpoints
    /// </summary>
    public int hp = 2;
    /// <summary>
    /// Score System
    /// </summary>
    public int score;
    GameObject player;
    /// <summary>
    /// Enemy or player?
    /// </summary>
    public bool isEnemy = true;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");


    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inflicts damage and check if the object should be destroyed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="damageCount"></param>
    public void Damage(int damageCount)
    {
        hp -= damageCount;
        SoundEffectsHelper.Instance.MakeplayerHitSound();



        if (hp <= 0)
        {



            SpecialEffectsHelper.Instance.Explosion(transform.position);
            SoundEffectsHelper.Instance.MakeExplosionSound();
            // Dead!



            if (isEnemy == false)
            {
                transform.parent.gameObject.AddComponent<GameOverScript>();
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
            if (isEnemy ==true)
            {
                ///when health reaches 0 object is destroyed and awards the player 100 points.
                player.GetComponent<ScoreScript>().score+=100;
                Destroy(gameObject);

            }            




        }
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        //display player information
        if (isEnemy == false)
        {
            GUI.color = Color.red;
            GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height - Screen.height, 248, 46), ("Health: " + hp.ToString()));

        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider)
    {
        // Is this a shot?
        ShotScript shot = otherCollider.gameObject.GetComponent<ShotScript>();
        if (shot != null)
        {

            // Avoid friendly fire
            if (shot.isEnemyShot != isEnemy)
            {
                Damage(shot.damage);

                // Destroy the shot
                Destroy(shot.gameObject); // Remember to always target the game object, otherwise you will just remove the script

            }

        }


    }




}
```